# How to run PHP locally on MacOS

Tags: php

I need a php sandbox on my local.

But I have to make just one class in PHP.

In NODE.JS I can do the following:

**test.js**

```js
// my test js script
console.log('hello world')
```

I can run it like this:

```sh
~$ node test.js
~$ hello world
~$
```

I would like to do something like this:

**test.php**

```php
echo('hello world');
```

I would like to run it like this:

```sh
~$ php test.php
~$ hello world
~$
```

Is there any way to do this, without installing apache and everything?
I just like to have a php sandbox on my mac.

Comment: Don't forget to start your test script with `<?php`

Comment: You might want to check https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php

Comment: Did you by any chance ***try*** running `php test.php`? MacOS comes with PHP and has for at least the last 10 years.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545077/best-lamp-environment-for-mac

Answer (score 9):

OSX comes with php installed :

```
$ which php # => /usr/bin/php
```

So you can run your php file. But don't forget to include your code between `<?php ... ?>`.

```
// test.php
<?php
echo("Hello world")
?>
```

So now you can run in your terminal:

```
$ php test.php
$ Hello world%
```

Apache is not needed.

Comment: PHP was removed in MacOS Monterey and following versions.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681907

Answer (score 7):

download and install xampp or any alternative that runs an Apache server on local machine should do the trick.

edit:
Just googled a little myself, apparently you can just download php and run the web server from cli now, $ php -S localhost:8000

Comment: You can write PHP programs that are server side scripts, but it is a general purpose programming language and entirely capable of being used to write command line or desktop apps.

Comment: yea, but don't you still need a server to run it though?

Comment: You don’t need a server to run a command line or desktop app.

Answer (score 6):

You can install only pah with Homebrew.

Make sure the brew is updated

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Install PHP 7.2

```
brew install php72
```

Wait for the installation to finish, you’re now running on PHP 7.2. You may run `$ php -v` to check the current PHP version on your machine.

now create file test.php

```
<?php
 echo "hello";
```

and run

```
php path/to/test.php
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to check if php is installed on your mac. Use the following command to check this :

```
php --version
```

Since PHP is installed by default on mac, you should get something like this:

> PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2020 18:19:30) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Once you've done that, you can create a PHP file containing just one line :

```
<?php echo "Hello world\n"; ?>
```

Output:

> Hello World

You only need PHP. You do not need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Apache and php are already installed on MacOS

Alternatively You can use docker or just find sandbox on-line, e.g. https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: No they're not. Many corporate machines will disable all this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I came into Mac, and before using Homebrew my temporary solution is [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/). Simply a quick solution that helped me work.

then there are articles that explain well how to create a lamp en mac development environment: [Setup Local (L)AMP Stack on Mac with Homebrew](https://medium.com/@JanFaessler/setup-local-lamp-stack-on-mac-with-homebrew-47eb8d6d53ea)

Comment: @Rajaswami did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a localhost. You can use XAMPP etc...